# Where does the Tomcat 7.0 console output go?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, console

I installed the latest tomcat 7 Windows service on windows 7 as an admin user.
[Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) doesn't say which file the console output gets redirected to. How can I find out ?

I issued a thread/stack dump request as per this [redhat article](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/19170). but would like to know where the jvm thread dump ended in. I looked for catalina.out but I couldn't find it in the TOMCAT install dir or installDir\logs dir.

Comment: Console output goes to catalina.out and/or catalina.YYYY-MM-DD in tomcat/logs. Both of them are missing?

Comment: yes catalina.out is missing. although I found catalina.YYY-MM-DD. but it didn't have the stack trace. where could that be ending up ?